# API to know if a node is alive?

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could run a system("rosnode ping -c1 /nodeName"), but this always return return code 0.
I could grep the standard output of rosnode, but it sounds quite dirty.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52457/api-to-know-if-a-node-is-alive?/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maero](https://answers.ros.org/users/4317/maero/) on 2014-09-30**:
did you manage to find out a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why you're checking for existence, but if your node provides an action, you can wait for the server to start with waitForServer.  You can also wait for a transform to become available with waitForTransform.

If you have other reasons, there's apparently a package, interface tester, that was designed to do this, but I can only find the [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/interface_testing), not the source. Maybe you'll have better luck finding it.

You could also use the [rosnode api](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/rosnode/html/). It's in python, and there might be [zombie nodes](http://answers.ros.org/question/9521/rosnode-zombies/), but it should give you what you need.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2013-01-16**:
If your node provides an action *or a service*. Or you could even have it publish on /i_am_alive...

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-08-13**:
The answer in #q164601 shows use of the rosnode api.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To extend on what @tbh said, if you're not using python, the internals of [rosnode](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/groovy-devel/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode/__init__.py).rosnode_ping() shows you how pinging a node works. It's basically just doing a xmlrpc call asking for the node's PID and seeing if that succeeds.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-29**:
To extend what others said: [rosnode _sub_rosnode_listnodes()](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/groovy-devel/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode/__init__.py#L256) shows that `rosnode list` gets nodes ...

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-29**:
... via [rosnode get_node_names()](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/e96c407c64e1c17b0dd2bb85b67f388380527097/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode/__init__.py#L117) from the rosgraph.